# Codeigniter - dropdown change to multiple select because use array as the name

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have problem with my dropdown. I need dropdown that can select only one value and I use the same dropdown to repeat the selection for others row. Here is my page look like

[Click here to view My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmFhD.png)

My code for the dropdown is

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=$rNumber;$i++){
   $occNo = array(
                    '1' => '1',
                    '2' => '2',
                    '3' => '3',
                    '4' => '4',
                    '5' => '5',
                    '6' => '6',
                    '7' => '7',
                    '8' => '8',
                    '9' => '9',
                    '10' => '10'
                    );
   echo form_dropdown('roomPax[]',$occNo,set_value('roomPax', isset($databaseData[$i]->roomPax) ? $databaseData[$i]->roomPax : ''),'class="form-control"');
}
?>
```

I found that, the dropdown change to multiple select because I use roomPax[] (array name). I have to use array name because the same dropdown I use for other row. How to set this dropdown as single select and maintain roomPax[] as their name?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define name as like that: `roomPax[]`
Just replace it with **roomPax** in first param of `form_dropdown()`

**From Codeigniter User Guide:**

> Lets you create a standard multiselect field. The first parameter will
>   contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an
>   associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the
>   value or values you wish to be selected. The parameter usage is
>   identical to using form_dropdown() above, except of course that the
>   name of the field will need to use POST array syntax, e.g. foo[].

As per user guide, when you need `multiselect` options than you can use your select `name` as an `array`.

Comment: as I mention, I need to use array as their name bcoz I use the same dropdown for other row. Refer here [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WmFhD.png)

Comment: means, you have two drop downs one single and one multi right? @AzmanMohdFarok

Comment: the code that you have share in question it will display the one drop down with 10 options right, and when i test it, it display the signle select drop down, now what you want? u want same array in another dropdown and dropdown should be multiselect? @AzmanMohdFarok

Comment: ya I know. But the code is inside for loop. That means, the same dropdown will be display row by row base on that for loop that I set (dynamic). That why I need to use array as their name so that when the user submit the form I can use foreach to retrieve dropdown value.

Comment: this is good to know actually u didnt post the complete code.. well if u can also add the loop in your question and i am trying my best.

Comment: @AzmanMohdFarok i get this value when i submit the form and $rNumber as 3: [roomPax] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 3
        )

Comment: @AzmanMohdFarok: when i use your code with for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++), .. it shows me 4 drop downs, single select drop down. and when i submit form it gives me.         Array
(
    [roomPax] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
        )

    [submit] => submit
)

Comment: when I load my page for the first time, all dropdown display as single select. After submit, I have form validation, if the form have error I'll show back the page with the error message. During that time my page display all dropdown as multiple select. That means, when I use redirect() it ok, but when I use load->view() to display error, dropdown change to multiple.

Comment: @AzmanMohdFarok: its working fine on my side, well try to use simple html code instead of CI function. just for test